# Reflexive space and separable spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, separable-spaces, reflexive-space

I read the definition of reflexive space and separable spaces, but I did not understand what was the point of studying them.

What is a reflexive Banach space? What is its interest in functional analysis?

The same question for a separable space.

An explanation please.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Why not consult the Wikipedia pages for these concepts and refine your question?

Comment: In a nutshell, a separable space is a space where everything regarding continuity reduces to study sequences on a set (for example, the rationals in the reals). While reflexivity simply means that the space is canonically identified with its second dual (no much more than that, really, honestly).

Comment: Maybe you should consider responding to / accepting answers to your old questions instead of posing again and again new ones.

Comment: @WillM. I think that could be an answer.